# Convert Hold Left Click to Multiple Left Clicks

Tags: python, onclick, click

I am trying to write a python program that would convert left click being held down to multiple left clicks. Essentially it just spams left click when left click is pressed down. I have written code that does this except that it gets stuck in a loop of because it triggers itself with the left clicks it sends. Here is my code:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
from threading import Thread
import pyautogui
import time

flag = False

def clicking():
    while flag:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click(button='left')
        print("Clicking...")


def clicked(x, y, button, pressed):
    global flag
    if pressed == True:
        if button == button.left:
            print("Left Click")
            flag = True
            thread = Thread(target=clicking)
            thread.start()
    else:
        flag = False


with Listener(on_click=clicked) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

How would I modify this code to stop if from triggering itself and getting stuck in a loop. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried anything of this sort, but I imagine you would check for `left.release` or something inside your `while` loop to break?

Comment: Nope, it just keeps on clicking.

Comment: you checked for release after you check for click inside of your while loop?

Comment: Wait i'll try again, now that I think about it it should work.

Comment: Sorry for the late update but I can confirm that does not work, just keeps on clicking. I'm guessing it can't tell between a mouse click and a `pyautogui` click and release.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code as an autoclicker you may be able to do some adjustments to set a listener to a left click.

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode, Key

def on_press(key):
if key == start_stop_key:
    if click_thread.running:
        click_thread.stop_clicking()
    else:
        click_thread.start_clicking()
elif key == exit_key:
    click_thread.exit()
    listener.stop()

class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, delay, button):
    super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
    self.delay = delay
    self.button = button
    self.running = False
    self.program_running = True

def start_clicking(self):
    self.running = True

def stop_clicking(self):
    self.running = False

def exit(self):
    self.stop_clicking()
    self.program_running = False

def run(self):
    while self.program_running:
        while self.running:
            mouse.click(self.button)
            time.sleep(self.delay)
        time.sleep(0.1)

start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='+')
#key to start
exit_key = KeyCode(char='¡')
#key to stop the iteration
button = Button.left
#Either Button.left or Button.right
delay = 0.1
#Time between clicks

click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
mouse = Controller()
click_thread.start()

with Listener(on_press = on_press) as listener:
listener.join()
```

Good luck